# Firebase real time database Batch update

Tags: swift, firebase-realtime-database

I have a list that can be deleted by a user with a click of a button. However, I cannot find documentation for firebase batch methods. Can someone point me in the right direction?

I want something like this..

```
Database.startBatch
for x in y {
            let ref = Network.database.child(x)
            ref.updateChildValues(status: done)
        }
Database.beginBatch
```